# Sharing Bundle identifier With Own Server OR Third Party Server

Tags: ios

I am trying to get bundle identifier from iOS and I can fetch it as below:

```
let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
```

Now my server team is asking for this value at a particular service call in POST.

I am able to share.

Now my questions are,

1. Is it secure to share bundleIdentifier with the server?
2. Does Apple allow to share the bundle identifier with own server or third-party server?

I am asking this question to avoid any security issue in future as I am working on Finance category app.

Comment: Simple answer, Yes it is save. It public information anyone with a little knowledge about iOS app can get from any app. But if you backend team is using it as a security restriction then that will be to easy to hack.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, sharing Bundle ID is completely secure.

Bundle ID is what identifies your app (authentication). It's not a secret (authorisation).

In fact, if your service provider decides to download your app, he/she can easily peel off your app bundle to obtain your bundle ID by doing the following:

- Get the .app file on mac
- Right click->Show Package Contents
- Open info.plist.

In fact, many legit 3rd party analytics firms / ad networks are already doing what I described above, in a much informational way - beyond just the bundle ID.

Everything related to the bundle is contained within this file.

What you should not share over the network contains following items:

- plain text / base64 encoded / not encrypted passwords
- app secrets with your third party providers
- any other data that you feel is considered confidential from finance app standpoint - in an easily decipherable format